# Accepting untrusted SSL certificate using webdriver for a window that opens up on clicking a menu option

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, ssl-certificate

upon clicking a menu option in my application , it opens a new window which opens an URL where SSL cert has to be accepted.

I have added code in my Webdriver connection class , like :-

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
firefoxprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxprofile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

But this particular scenario is not getting handled by the above code...and I still get the untrusted SSL cert .... I am not sure how to handle this...

Comment: Have tried with true in following line ?  profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);

Comment: Thanks ! .. I did two things and it worked :- 1) set firefoxprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true); 2) I fetched the URL by its href attribute tag from the xpath and opened it in a new window and things worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

`FirefoxProfile firefoxprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
firefoxprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxprofile);`